# Is there some way to edit multiple rows simultaneously in XCode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

The one thing I miss when using Xcode, having spent most of my career in Visual Studio and having, for the most part, come to prefer Xcode over the last few years, is the ability to edit multiple rows of text simultaneously.

In VS, this is accomplished by alt-dragging a columnar selection, then typing. Whatever you type appears on all rows at once. So you can convert this:

```
glVertex2f( 1, -1 );
glVertex2f( 1,  0 );
glVertex2f( 1,  1 );
```

...to this...

```
glVertex2f( -1, -1 );
glVertex2f( -1,  0 );
glVertex2f( -1,  1 );
```

...with a single keystroke. Or perhaps you meant to type "glVertex2i". All those f's can turn to i's in a moment. This feature is amazingly handy in a wide variety of situations.

Xcode also allows columnar selection with alt+drag. However, after making such a selection, typing only modifies the first row of text, as if only the first row had been selected.

Is there an option, a plugin—anything—that enables multi-row editing in Xcode?

I'm currently in version 4.3.1, BTW.

Comment: Doesn't work with paste either. Pity. I miss this too. I'm off to file an enhancement request with Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution but maybe this can help you...

[image: Edit all in scope]

Comment: This does not solve the use case in the question (adding a '-' in several rows at once).